# Replacement of an ampersand in xml document after encodings/decodings

Tags: python, replace

How do i replace a amphersand with the html sign & in a xml document?
normally it works simply with

```
a = u"TORE & Co & KG"
i = a.replace('&','&amp;')
print i
```

Here it doesn't work:i get my xml structure out of an email and process it like this:

```
saver=StringIO(u"") # Edit
a=str(msg)
i= a.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
saver.write(i)
savercontent = saver.getvalue()
savercontent.replace('&','&amp;')
```

In the end the replacement dosen't work...no errors..., how can i fix this? I guess this is connected with the encodings/decodings... Any help?

Comment: Can you show what `savercontent` is?

Comment: thanks for asking: saver and savercontent come from StringIO(u"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
a = str(msg)
i = a.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8').replace('&', '&amp;')
saver.write(i)
savercontent = saver.getvalue()
```

Or try:

```
i = a.decode('quopri').replace('&', '&amp;').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: is there a way to replace it by typing the unicode signature?

Comment: @Jurudocs Im not too well versed with encodings so Im not sure how you could use the unicode signature (dont even know what that is, tbh).  Check my edits though.

Comment: @ chown: thanks a lot that worked for me...you really saved my night! no a ment the unicode signs...forget the signature ;-P

Answer (score 3):

may be change

```
savercontent.replace('&','&amp;')
```

to

```
savercontent = savercontent.replace('&','&amp;')
```

Comment: @ Andrey: that also works...Thanks for your help +1 but i personally prefer the replacement before writing into stringIO